# Error when inserting boolean values with Diesel into PostgreSQL database

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

```
let _ = diesel::insert_into(like::table)
       .values(&like)
       .load::<Like>(&db.connection)
       .unwrap();
```

On `&db.connection` i get the following error

```
the trait bound bool: FromSql<Integer, _> is not satisfied
the trait FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Bool, Pg> is implemented for bool
required for bool to implement Queryable<Integer, _>
```

I tried to implement this approach by using `CustomBool`, but anyway i get the same error but for `CustomBool`

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, FromSqlRow)]
pub struct CustomBool(bool);

impl FromSql<SqlBool, Pg> for CustomBool {
    fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&[u8]>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
        match bytes {
            Some(bytes) => Ok(CustomBool(bytes[0] != 0)),
            None => Ok(CustomBool(false)),
        }
    }
}

impl ToSql<SqlBool, Pg> for CustomBool {
    fn to_sql<W: Write>(&self, out: &mut Output<W, Pg>) -> serialize::Result {
        ToSql::<diesel::sql_types::Integer, Pg>::to_sql(&(self.0 as i32), out)
    }
}

#[derive(Queryable, Identifiable, Associations, Debug)]
#[belongs_to(User, Post)]
#[table_name="like"]
pub struct Like {
    pub id: i32,
    pub reaction: CustomBool,
    pub post_id: i32,
    pub user_id: i32
}
```

My schema

```
diesel::table! {
    like (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        user_id -> Int4,
        post_id -> Int4,
        reaction -> Bool,
    }
}
```

I am stuck with this problem, and would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this problem is in mismatching order between schema and model properties. In my case `reaction` should be the last item

```
pub struct Like {
    pub id: i32,
    pub post_id: i32,
    pub user_id: i32,
    pub reaction: bool,
}
```